# File transfer software with a settings locked client

Tags: windows, file-transfer

We have need to have technicians move pictures from a local computer to our server in another office. Currently we have an office staff member copying them over a remote desktop connection, however this is slow, and we want the techs to do it themselves.

My first instinct is to use FTP for this, however, a normal FTP client is a bit beyond some of their computer skills. I am hoping to find a client that I can lock to a specific server, destination folder, and credentials. So they can just select the files and hit upload.

In brief, I am looking for an app they can start, select the files, click upload. The files will be sorted into the correct place on the server by someone in that office.

If anyone has any suggestions they will be greatly appreciated. I have been coming up with a goose egg on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Explorer as a drag & drop FTP client. Maybe you can give them a desktop shortcut something like

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,FTP://yourserver.example.com/
```

The can then drag image files from another Windows explorer window and drop them onto the window for the FTP server.

See [Default installed ftp client on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/214947/default-installed-ftp-client-on-windows/214952#214952)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FTP server and create link on the with target:

%windir%\explorer.exe "ftp://example.com/"

which will open up the remote folder just like a local one, provided they can work with windows explorer, there shouldn't be a problem.