# Default installed ftp client on windows

Tags: windows, ftp

I am distributing a product that allow some access using FTP. I am looking for a simple way to connect to that service from the most generic Windows box. Installing an external ftp client, makes the process of connecting to my product more tricky than I like it to be.

So my question is:

Is there an ftp client that can do all of the following:

- connect on a non standard port.
- authenticate with username and password.
- upload a file.

Here is what I already tried:

- I had no success uploading a file with Internet Explorer.
- I had no success authenticating using Windows Explorer.
- I had no success connecting to a non standard port with `ftp` command from the command line.

Am I missing something?

---

Edit: My bad. Apparently I was hitting the `max_connection` limit on my server. So the answer for my question is: **Windows Explorer do all of the above**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can authenticate with Internet Explorer by including the credentials in the URL, however it will prompt for username and password if you don't enter them.

```
ftp://username:password@host.example.com/path/to/files
```

I haven't tried it but I would expect a non-standard port to be specified in the usual way

```
ftp://username:password@host.example.com:10021/path/to/files
```

You can specify a port on the command line like this

```
C:\> ftp
ftp> open host.example.com 10021
```

---

UPDATE: The Windows explorer address bar usually shows drive letter and path (e.g. `C:\somewhere`) but you can type in a URL like those above, it can then be used as a drag&drop target for uploading a file to an FTP server.

Comment: The URL you gave is correct, just note that IE does not present a target that allow drag & drop, nor copy & paste. WE does. The ftp command line is correct. But the `help open` documentation is poor. It says: `open   Connect to remote tftp`

Comment: `explorer.exe`'s built-in FTP client does support drag&drop and copy&paste, but that is all. It doesn't support opening files in default programs and those sorts of things. However, you can vote in feedback to make it better: https://aka.ms/Fjpi0y